# Sharepoont 2010 webpart vb.net Listbox SelectIndexChanged and errors

Tags: vb.net-2010

So let start I am new to coding widgets and in general. I had originally coded this in vb for asp pages and it work fine. Now converting over to a SharePoint 2010 webpart (not visual webpart).
The project is List box 1 has the user groups that they manage, List box 2 has the users in said group, List box 3 has all user not in List box 2

I am sure there lots of this that should be fix. Like not putting in admin login to get the data.
But the problem I have is: if select a group it will display the appropriate data but select a second group or select a user to add; same error.

Error:
 "Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request."

Also still trying to figure out how to do the button to add a user.
Need some serious help please. I know part of the post back just having a hard time finding resources.

Below is the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls
Imports ActiveDs
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.Data
Imports ADODB
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


<ToolboxItemAttribute(False)> _
Public Class Groups
Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart


Private LBgrp As ListBox
Private LBgrpmem As ListBox
Private LBaddgrp As ListBox
Private btnadd As Button

Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()


    Me.LBgrpmem = New ListBox
    Me.LBgrpmem.AutoPostBack = True
    Me.LBgrpmem.DataValueField = "sAMAccountName"
    Me.LBgrpmem.DataTextField = "displayName"
    Me.LBgrpmem.DataBind()
    Me.LBgrpmem.Rows = 8
    Me.LBgrpmem.Width = 170
    Me.LBgrpmem.Height = 350
    Me.LBgrpmem.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-- Current Members --"))
    Me.Controls.Add(LBgrpmem)

    Me.LBaddgrp = New ListBox
    Me.LBaddgrp.AutoPostBack = True
    Me.LBaddgrp.DataTextField = "displayName"
    Me.LBaddgrp.DataValueField = "sAMAccountName"
    Me.LBaddgrp.DataBind()
    Me.LBaddgrp.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-- Add Users --"))
    Me.LBaddgrp.Width = 170
    Me.LBaddgrp.Height = 350
    AddHandler LBaddgrp.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf DLAdd_SelectedIndexChanged)
    Me.Controls.Add(LBaddgrp)

    Me.btnadd = New Button()
    ' AddHandler Me.btnadd.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf Click_btnadd)
    Me.btnadd.Text = "Add User"
    Me.Controls.Add(btnadd)


End Sub


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load




    Dim oRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim sDomainADsPath = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Dim oCon As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oCmd As New ADODB.Command

    Dim sFullUser As String = Environment.UserName

    Dim sProperties = "name,ADsPath,description,member,memberof,managedObjects"
    Dim sGroup = "*"
    Dim aMember
    Dim iCount

    oCon.ToString()
    oCmd.ToString()
    sFullUser.ToString()
    sProperties.ToString()
    sDomainADsPath.ToString()

    oCon.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon.Open("ADProvider", "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD")
    oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    oCmd.CommandText = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & sFullUser & "));" & sProperties & ";subtree"
    oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute


    Dim de As DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(sDomainADsPath, "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD", DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim sl As SortedList = New SortedList(New CaseInsensitiveComparer)
    de.ToString()

    While Not oRecordSet.EOF

        aMember = oRecordSet.Fields("managedObjects").Value
        If Not IsDBNull(aMember) Then
            For iCount = 0 To UBound(aMember)
                Dim groupDN As String = ("distinguishedName=" & aMember(iCount))
                Dim src As DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher = New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=Group)(" & groupDN & "))")
                src.SearchRoot = de
                src.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree
                For Each res As DirectoryServices.SearchResult In src.FindAll
                    sl.Add(res.Properties("name")(0).ToString, i)
                    i += 1
                Next


            Next
        End If
        oRecordSet.MoveNext()
    End While

    Me.LBgrp = New ListBox
    Me.LBgrp.AutoPostBack = True
    Me.LBgrp.DataSource = sl
    Me.LBgrp.DataTextField = "key"
    Me.LBgrp.DataValueField = "value"
    Me.LBgrp.DataBind()
    Me.LBgrp.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-- Groups --"))
    Me.Controls.Add(LBgrp)
    Me.LBgrp.SelectedIndex = 0
    AddHandler LBgrp.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf LBgrp_SelectedIndexChanged)
    LBgrp.SelectedItem.ToString()

End Sub


Protected Sub LBgrp_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles LBgrp.SelectedIndexChanged


    Dim strQuery As String = "" & LBgrp.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() & "'"



    'LBgrpmem.Items.Clear()
    Dim oRootDSE2 = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim sDomainADsPath2 = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE2.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Dim oCon2 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordSet2 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sFullUser2 As String = Environment.UserName
    Dim oCmd2 As New ADODB.Command
    Dim sProperties2 = "name,ADsPath,description,member,memberof,managedObjects"
    Dim grpADsPath2
    Dim grpdsplynm2
    oRootDSE2 = Nothing
    oCon2.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon2.Open("ADProvider", "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD")
    oCmd2.ActiveConnection = oCon2
    oCmd2.CommandText = "<" & sDomainADsPath2 & ">;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(CN=" & LBgrp.SelectedItem.Text & "));" & sProperties2 & ";subtree"

    oRecordSet2 = oCmd2.Execute
    While oRecordSet2.EOF
        grpADsPath2 = oRecordSet2.Fields("ADsPath").Value
        grpADsPath2.ToString()

        grpdsplynm2 = grpADsPath2.remove(0, 7)
        grpdsplynm2.ToString()
        oRecordSet2.MoveNext()
    End While

    While Not oRecordSet2.EOF
        grpADsPath2 = oRecordSet2.Fields("ADsPath").Value
        grpADsPath2.ToString()

        grpdsplynm2 = grpADsPath2.remove(0, 7)
        grpdsplynm2.ToString()
        oRecordSet2.MoveNext()
    End While
    Dim groupDN2 As String = "" & grpdsplynm2 & ""
    Dim filter As String = [String].Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(memberOf={0}))", groupDN2)

    Me.LBgrpmem.AutoPostBack = True
    Me.LBgrpmem.DataSource = FindUsers(filter, New String() {"sAMAccountName", "displayName"}, sDomainADsPath2, True)
    Me.LBgrpmem.DataValueField = "sAMAccountName"
    Me.LBgrpmem.DataTextField = "displayName"
    Me.LBgrpmem.DataBind()
    Me.LBgrpmem.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-- Current Members --"))
    Me.Controls.Add(LBgrpmem)

    Dim usrDN As String = "" & grpdsplynm2 & ""
    usrDN.ToString()
    Dim usrfilter As String = [String].Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!memberOf={0}))", groupDN2)

    Me.LBaddgrp.AutoPostBack = True
    Me.LBaddgrp.DataSource = FindUsers(usrfilter, New String() {"sAMAccountName", "displayName"}, sDomainADsPath2, True)
    Me.LBaddgrp.DataTextField = "displayName"
    Me.LBaddgrp.DataValueField = "sAMAccountName"
    Me.LBaddgrp.DataBind()
    Me.LBaddgrp.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-- Add Users --"))
    'AddHandler LBaddgrp.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf DLAdd_SelectedIndexChanged)
    Me.Controls.Add(LBaddgrp)


End Sub

Public Function FindUsers(ByVal sFilter As String, ByVal columns() As String, ByVal path As String, ByVal useCached As Boolean) As Data.DataSet

    Dim oRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim sDomainADsPath = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

    'try to retrieve from cache first
    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    Dim userDS As Data.DataSet = CType(context.Cache(sFilter), Data.DataSet)

    If userDS Is Nothing Or Not useCached Then
        'setup the searching entries
        Dim deParent As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(sDomainADsPath, "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD", DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure)

        Dim ds As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(deParent, sFilter, columns, DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree)

        ds.PageSize = 1000
        ds.Sort.PropertyName = "displayName" 'sort option

        Using (deParent)
            userDS = New Data.DataSet("userDS")
            Dim dt As Data.DataTable = userDS.Tables.Add("users")
            Dim dr As Data.DataRow

            'add each parameter as a column
            Dim prop As String
            For Each prop In columns
                dt.Columns.Add(prop, GetType(String))
            Next prop

            Dim src As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection = ds.FindAll
            Try
                Dim sr As DirectoryServices.SearchResult
                For Each sr In src
                    dr = dt.NewRow()
                    For Each prop In columns
                        If sr.Properties.Contains(prop) Then
                            dr(prop) = sr.Properties(prop)(0)
                        End If
                    Next prop
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                Next sr
            Finally
                src.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Using
        'cache it for later, with sliding window
        context.Cache.Insert(sFilter, userDS, Nothing, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    End If
    Return userDS
End Function 'FindUsers


Protected Sub DLAdd_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles Click_btnadd

    Dim oRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim sDomainADsPath = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Dim oCon As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oRcrdSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oCmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim oCmd1 As New ADODB.Command
    Dim sGroup = "*"
    Dim sProperties = "name,ADsPath,description,member,memberof,proxyAddresses"
    Dim grpADsPath
    Dim grpdsplynm
    Dim addusrADsPath
    Dim addusrname


    oRootDSE = Nothing
    oCon.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon.Open("ADProvider", "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD")
    oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    oCmd1.ActiveConnection = oCon

    oCmd.CommandText = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectClass=group)(cn=" & LBgrp.SelectedItem.Text & "));" & sProperties & ";subtree"
    oRecordSet = oCmd.Execute
    'Group Query
    While Not oRecordSet.EOF
        grpADsPath = oRecordSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value
        grpdsplynm = oRecordSet.Fields("name").Value
        oRecordSet.MoveNext()
    End While

    oCmd1.CommandText = "<" & sDomainADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn=" & LBaddgrp.SelectedItem.Text & "));" & sProperties & ";subtree"
    oRcrdSet = oCmd1.Execute
    'User query
    While Not oRcrdSet.EOF
        addusrADsPath = oRcrdSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value
        addusrname = oRcrdSet.Fields("name").Value
        oRcrdSet.MoveNext()
    End While

    ' Bind directly to the group
    '

    Dim oRootDSE2 = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim sDomainADsPath2 = "LDAP://" & oRootDSE2.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Dim oCon2 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordSet2 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sFullUser2 As String = Environment.UserName
    'Dim sFullUser2 = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
    'Dim sUser2 = Split(sFullUser2, "\", -1)
    Dim oCmd2 As New ADODB.Command
    Dim sProperties2 = "name,ADsPath,description,member,memberof,managedObjects"
    Dim grpADsPath2
    oRootDSE2 = Nothing
    oCon2.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    oCon2.Open("ADProvider", "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD")
    oCmd2.ActiveConnection = oCon2
    oCmd2.CommandText = "<" & sDomainADsPath2 & ">;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(CN=" & LBgrp.SelectedItem.Text & "));" & sProperties2 & ";subtree"

    oRecordSet2 = oCmd2.Execute
    While Not oRecordSet2.EOF
        grpADsPath2 = oRecordSet2.Fields("ADsPath").Value
        oRecordSet2.MoveNext()
    End While


    Dim group As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("" & grpADsPath2 & "", "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD", DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure)

    Dim user As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(addusrADsPath, "ADMINUSER@Domain.com", "ADMINPASSWORD", DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure)


    Dim isMember As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(group.Invoke("IsMember", New Object() {user.Path}))
    If isMember Then
        '
        ' TO CREATE ERROR MESSAGE
    Else
        ' Add the user to the group by invoking the Add method
        '
        group.Invoke("Add", New Object() {user.Path})
    End If

    If Not IsNothing(user) Then
        user.Dispose()
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(group) Then
        group.Dispose()
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()

    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        ' TO CREATE ERROR MESSAGE
    Else
        ' TO CREATE SUCCESS MESSAGE
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)


    LBgrp.RenderControl(writer)
    LBgrpmem.RenderControl(writer)
    LBaddgrp.RenderControl(writer)
    btnadd.RenderControl(writer)


End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: nice thing to do would be to clean up the code and remove debugging stuff from the code example, it helps people read your code and understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if memory serves me correctly, Page_Load event is firing on a postback too, where you are trying to create another instance of your drop down. So the system is trying to recreate the state of ListBox from ViewState but it is not the same ListBox, because you have just recreated it. So it barks.

To avoid it, in the page_load only create "parent" drop down if it's not postback. i.e.

```
Begin Page_Load()
    If !Page.IsPostBack() Then 
         'load code here
    End If
End Page_Load
```

Also there's no need to write 
   Me.LBgrpmem = New ListBox

as it is already created. Changing the datasource is usually enuff.

Comment: If I remove the Me.LBgrpmem = New ListBox I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You're right. Here's a good link http://bilbrobloggins.com/sharepoint/dropdown-list-box-filter-web-part-in-sharepoint-ndash-part-two/

looks like all initial data binding needs to happen in OnLoad event after checking for IsPostBack.

Comment: So i figured the post back problem, Thank you. I add "If Page.IsPostBack Then" on both Protected Sub _SelectedIndexChanged. next step to figure out how to get the button working...Thank you again.